# How to resolve this using STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I have this problem: There are 5 people, in a matrimonial, to obtain the best choice each of them  are told to answer some 10 multiple choice questions with 4 options: A, B, C, D. Now the best match refers to the person having highest "similarity factor" (sf). E.g if Dick and Lisa have got 6 answers correct, and sf=3 (>6), then Dick and Lisa are good prospective partners, similarly we have to find other partners as well with answers may be 5, 4 or least 3 same as correct as Lisa since sf=3.

```
members is a string array having list of all members, first field is name, next is sex,     
next are answers to multiple choice questions:

 For this, i have a string array called "members"
 members[ ] = {"Dick, M, A, B, C, A, B...(10 answers)",
          "Lisa, F, A, D, C, B, B...(10 answers)",
          "Harry,M, A, B, A, D, C...(10 answers)",
          "Mira",F, A, B, C, C, A...(10 answers)"
          .
          .
          <snip>
         };
```

The first field in string is name, second field shows sex, M or F, the others shows the 10 multiple choice questions answers.

Now, using STL what is the quickest method to find the similarity factor (same answers in multiple choice questions)?

I know about string tokenization, and adding these individual fields in a STL vector. But how to find the similarity factor? I know the conventional ways( going one by one and checking), but is there any quick method for comparison using STLs?

A code snippet will be of immense help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want, but if you get all the answers into a [`valarray<std::string>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/valarray/), you can compare these directly. The result is a `valarray<bool>`, which contains `true` if the corresponding elements were equal, and `false` otherwise. You can then count how often they were equal using:

```
std::valarray<bool> = (answers1 == answers2);
int count = std::count(&comp_array[0], &comp_array[0]+comp_array.size(), true);
```

Comment: So you mean, if there are 10 people we need 10 valarrays for comparision?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try making a std::set out of the question answers. You would then have access to methods like set_difference, set_intersection. 
My first idea would be to transform your members string array into something more convenient to process.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html